# c# mysql insert statement. Parameterized query example?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, parameterized-query

I'm trying to get this `insert` statement to work.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (apellido,nombre,email,password,id_localidad) "
                         + "VALUES (?apellido,?nombre,?email,?password,?idLocalidad); ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("apellido ", usuario.apellido);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombre ", usuario.nombre);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email ", usuario.email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password ", password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idLocalidad ", usuario.localidad.idLocalidad);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but yet again, i get an exception saying ***first parameter needs to be defined***. If I use the `@` placeholder, i get a `null` error when clearly I'm adding parameters. I also added the following to my connection string.

```
AllowUserVariables=True
```

I know variants of this question have appeared throughout the site, but I have followed advice provided and still haven't been able to make it work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the code with `@ placeholder` that you have tried?

Comment: string sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (apellido,nombre,email,password,id_localidad) "
                         + "VALUES (@apellido,@nombre,@email,@password,@idLocalidad); ";

Comment: And how you add parameters?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido ", usuario.apellido);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre ", usuario.nombre);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email ", usuario.email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password ", password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idLocalidad ", usuario.localidad.idLocalidad);

Comment: Looks good. let me know the line which gives such exception? this time

Comment: says the first column cannot be null, and it is not

Comment: are you sure usuario.appellido is not null?

Comment: positive. i'm seeing the output in the debugger

Comment: could you try this one: `cmd.Parameters.Add("?apellido", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario.apellido;`

Comment: @currarpickt you sir/madam, are a genius. If you want to add this comment as the answer, i'll mark it as such. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to specify `MySQLDbType` to match your DB Type and use `Add` function:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?apellido", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usuario.apellido;
```